# How to model packages, versions and licenses?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm currently a bit stuck. The question is around npm packages, their versions/releases and their licenses.

Here is a simple license

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS license (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    reference TEXT NOT NULL,
    is_deprecated_license_id BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    reference_number INTEGER NOT NULL,
    license_id TEXT NOT NULL,
    is_osi_approved BOOLEAN NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO license
     ("name",reference,is_deprecated_license_id,reference_number,license_id,is_osi_approved)
VALUES
     ('Academic Free License v2.0','./AFL-2.0.json',false,0,'AFL-2.0',true);
```

Here is my package

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS npm_package (
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    description TEXT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO npm_package 
    (name, description)
VALUES
    ('react', 'React is a JavaScript library for building user interfaces.'),
    ('react-router-dom', 'DOM bindings for React Router'),
    ('typescript', 'TypeScript is a language for application scale JavaScript development'),
    ('react-dom', 'React package for working with the DOM.');
```

A package has multiple versions and each version has license, e.g.

- react - 1.0.0 - MIT
- react - 2.0.0 - BSD
- react - 3.0.0 - MIT
- ...

The version is just a semver string.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS npm_version (
    npm_package_id BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES npm_package,
    version TEXT NOT NULL,
    license_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES license
)
```

Now I'm trying to model this with Spring Boot and Hibernate. Here is what I've got so far.

```
@Entity
public class License {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;

  private String reference;

  private Boolean isDeprecatedLicenseId;

  private Integer referenceNumber;

  private String name;

  private String licenseId;

  private Boolean isOsiApproved;
}
```

And here is my npm package.

```
@Entity
public class NpmPackage {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  private String name;

  private String description;
}
```

Now I want to combine packages, their versions and their licenses. How would I proceed using Hibernate? The query I'm looking for is something like "Give me all releases for 'react' with their according license"

Thank you very much!

---

Edit 24/03/2021

I did some more research and got a bit further. Let's remove the license for now and focus and packages and versions.

Here is how I create a package.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS npm_package (
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    description TEXT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO npm_package 
    (name, description)
VALUES
    ('react', 'React is a JavaScript library for building user interfaces.'),
    ('react-router-dom', 'DOM bindings for React Router'),
    ('typescript', 'TypeScript is a language for application scale JavaScript development'),
    ('react-dom', 'React package for working with the DOM.');
```

Here is how I create a version. A version should not need an extra identifier. The combination of package and version is unique.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS npm_package_version (
    npm_package_id BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES npm_package,
    version TEXT NOT NULL,

    UNIQUE(npm_package_id, version)
)
```

Here is `NpmPackage.java`

```
@Entity
public class NpmPackage {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany
  private List<NpmPackageVersion> versions;

  private String name;

  private String description;
}
```

Here is `NpmPackageVersion.java`

```
@Entity
public class NpmPackageVersion {

    @EmbeddedId
    private NpmPackageIdVersion npmPackageIdVersion;

    @MapsId("npmPackageId")
    @ManyToOne
    private NpmPackage npmPackage;

    @Embeddable
    public class NpmPackageIdVersion implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 3357194191099820556L;

        private Long npmPackageId;

        private String version;
    }
}
```

Without the `@MapsId` I got

> Table [npm_package_version] contains physical column name [npm_package_id] referred to by multiple logical column names: [npm_package_id], [npmPackageId]

With `@MapsId` I get

> Schema-validation: missing column [versions_npm_package_id] in table [npm_package_versions]

When I rename the column to `versions_npm_package_id` I get

> Schema-validation: missing column [npm_package_id] in table [npm_package_versions]

I'm running in circles and not getting anywhere. Never felt so stupid in a long time. I'm still waiting for the "click" event whenever I start working with new technology. That unfortunately hasn't happened yet :)

Any ideas?

Comment: Which part of the task is problematic? You should have a `@OneToMany @JoinColumn private List<Version> versions` in `NpmPackage`, and a `@ManyToOne private License license` in `Version`. See [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToOne) and [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany) for examples

Comment: I am new to Hibernate and maybe my mental model is too complicated at the moment.

I also have the problem that Hibernate complains about the missing Id: No identifier specified for entity NpmVersion.

Comment: Every entity needs to have an id. You'll need an `id` for `NpmVersion`, similar to the one in `NpmPackage`. Alternatively, you could create and map a [composite primary key](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jpa/derived-composite-keys.html) comprised of the package id and version string

Comment: I don't want to create an extra identity column for `npm_version`. It is more like a join table. That means I have to use `@EmbeddedId`, right?

Comment: You could use `@EmbeddedId` or `@IdClass`, whichever appeals to you

Comment: I added some more information but haven't found the solution yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close to the finding the solution.

The following setup works:

**NpmPackage**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "npm_package")
public class NpmPackage {

  public NpmPackage(String name, String description) {
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
  }

  public NpmPackage() {
  }

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  private String name;

  private String description;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "npmPackage", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  private List<NpmPackageVersion> versions = new ArrayList<>();

  ...//getters and setters

  public void addVersion(NpmPackageVersion version) {
    this.versions.add(version);
    version.setNpmPackage(this);
  }

  public void removeVersion(NpmPackageVersion version) {
    this.versions.remove(version);
  }
}
```

**NpmPackageVersion**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "npm_package_version")
public class NpmPackageVersion {

    public NpmPackageVersion(String version, License license) {
        setVersion(version);
        this.license = license;
    }

    public NpmPackageVersion() {
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    private NpmPackageIdVersion npmPackageIdVersion = new NpmPackageIdVersion();

    @MapsId("npmPackageId")
    @ManyToOne
    private NpmPackage npmPackage;

    @ManyToOne
    private License license;

    public String getVersion() {
        return npmPackageIdVersion.version;
    }

    public void setVersion(String version) {
        npmPackageIdVersion.version = version;
    }

    ...//getters and setters

    @Embeddable
    public static class NpmPackageIdVersion implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 3357194191099820556L;

        private Long npmPackageId;

        private String version;

        ... //getters and setters etc.
    }
}
```

**License**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "license")
public class License {

    public License() {}

    public License(String name, String licenseId) {
        this.name = name;
        this.licenseId = licenseId;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String reference;

    @Column(name = "is_deprecated_license_id")
    private boolean deprecatedLicenseId;

    private Integer referenceNumber;

    private String name;

    private String licenseId;

    @Column(name = "is_osi_approved")
    private boolean osiApproved;

    ... //getters and setters
}
```

I used the following code to test it:

```
@Transactional
public NpmPackage createPackage() {
        License license = new License("General Public License", "GPL 2.0");
        em.persist(license);
        NpmPackage npmPackage = new NpmPackage("react", "React Framework");
        npmPackage.addVersion(new NpmPackageVersion("8.11.0", license));
        em.persist(npmPackage);
}
```

Comment: One last question: If I don't like to use `FetchType.EAGER`, how would that work? At the moment I'm getting an error.

> Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.example.bom.NpmPackage.NpmPackage.versions, could not initialize proxy - no Session

Comment: If you switch to `LAZY`, you need to still be in the context of a transaction (while the session is still open) when accessing `NpmPackage.versions`. Another option, if you're seeing two queries being issued for each package and are worried about performance, is to put `@Fetch(JOIN)` on top of `versions`. You can also use a join fetch: `SELECT p FROM NpmPackage p JOIN FETCH p.versions` when needed. Finally, with the embedded id, you could simply query for all the versions: `SELECT v FROM NpmPackage Version v WHERE v.npmPackageIdVersion.npmPackageId = :id`

Comment: Not sure if that answers your question