# I'm trying to understand LazyInitializationException and @Transactional

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

This is a follow-up question to my previous one [How to model packages, versions and licenses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66761888/how-to-model-packages-versions-and-licenses).

Here is my database setup.

`V1__create_table_license.sql`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS license (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    reference TEXT NOT NULL,
    is_deprecated_license_id BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    reference_number INTEGER NOT NULL,
    license_id TEXT NOT NULL,
    is_osi_approved BOOLEAN NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO license
  ("name",reference,is_deprecated_license_id,reference_number,license_id,is_osi_approved)
VALUES
  ('MIT License','./MIT.json',false,275,'MIT',true);
```

`V2__create_npm_package.sql`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS npm_package (
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    description TEXT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO npm_package 
    (name, description)
VALUES
    ('react', 'React is a JavaScript library for building user interfaces.'),
    ('react-router-dom', 'DOM bindings for React Router'),
    ('typescript', 'TypeScript is a language for application scale JavaScript development'),
    ('react-dom', 'React package for working with the DOM.');
```

`V3__create_npm_version.sql`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS npm_package_version (
    npm_package_id BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES npm_package,
    version TEXT NOT NULL,
    license_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES license,

    UNIQUE(npm_package_id, version)
)
```

Here are my Java objects.

`License.java`

```
@Entity
public class License {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;

  private String reference;

  private Boolean isDeprecatedLicenseId;

  private Integer referenceNumber;

  private String name;

  private String licenseId;

  private Boolean isOsiApproved;
}
```

`LicenseRepository.java`

```
public interface LicenseRepository extends JpaRepository<License, Integer> {
  License findByLicenseIdIgnoreCase(String licenseId);
}
```

`NpmPackage.java`

```
@Entity
public class NpmPackage {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  private String name;

  private String description;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "npmPackage", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  private List<NpmPackageVersion> versions = new ArrayList<>();

  public NpmPackage() {}

  public void addVersion(NpmPackageVersion version) {
    this.versions.add(version);
    version.setNpmPackage(this);
  }

  public void removeVersion(NpmPackageVersion version) {
    this.versions.remove(version);
    version.setNpmPackage(null);
  }
}
```

```
@Entity
public class NpmPackageVersion {

  public NpmPackageVersion() {}

  public NpmPackageVersion(String version, License license) {
    this.setVersion(version);
    this.license = license;
  }

  @EmbeddedId private NpmPackageIdVersion npmPackageIdVersion = new NpmPackageIdVersion();

  @MapsId("npmPackageId")
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private NpmPackage npmPackage;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private License license;

  @Embeddable
  public static class NpmPackageIdVersion implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3357194191099820556L;

    private Long npmPackageId;
    private String version;

    // ...
  }

  public String getVersion() {
    return this.npmPackageIdVersion.version;
  }

  public void setVersion(String version) {
    this.npmPackageIdVersion.version = version;
  }
}
```

`MyRunner.java`

```
@Component
class MyRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

  @Autowired LicenseRepository licenseRepository;

  @Autowired NpmPackageRepository npmPackageRepository;

  @Override
  // @Transactional
  public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    // get license from database
    var license = licenseRepository.findByLicenseIdIgnoreCase("mit");

    // get package from db
    var dbPackage = npmPackageRepository.findByNameIgnoreCase("react");

    var version = new NpmPackageVersion("1.0.0", license);

    dbPackage.addVersion(version);
    
    npmPackageRepository.save(dbPackage);
  }
}
```

In my previous question I got the answer to use `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` but then I learned that this is not ideal. I'd like to use lazy fetching.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "npmPackage", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<NpmPackageVersion> versions = new ArrayList<>();
```

So I removed the eager fetching and run into an error.

> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.example.bom.NpmPackage.NpmPackage.versions, could not initialize proxy - no Session

With the `@Transactional` annotation everything works. Why is this the case? I tried to read everything online but I still don't really get it. I understand that the database session is closed at some point and I wonder where exactly this is the case. I also wonder if I could do something about, e.g. I tried to fetch all versions to ensure they are loaded before I add another one.

So do I really have to use `@Transactional` or is there another solution? I just want to understand the "magic" going on :)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

When you use `FetchType.LAZY`, Hibernate ORM doesn't really return an initialized collection when you find the entity. The association is going to be a proxy and when you need access to the collection, Hibernate ORM is going to query the database and get it.

To achieve this, the entity (the `NpmPackage`) needs to be in a managed state. If the entity is not managed and you try to access a lazy association (`versions` in this case), you get the `LazyInitializationException`.

In your example, when you use `@Transactional`, the entity stays managed for the duration of the method. Without it, it becomes not managed as soon as you return from `findByNameIgnoreCase`.

If you know that you will need the association `versions`, you could also use a fetch join query to get the `NpmPackage`:

```
from NpmPackage p left join fetch p.versions where p.name=:name
```

This way the associations stays lazy but you can get it with a single query.

Comment: Thank you. I think that's also what I read elsewhere. I'm wondering how is `EAGER` different to your `fetch join`?

Comment: It's the same thing. But if you declare it on the association, the association will always be EAGER (it doesn't matter how you get the entity).

Comment: If you do it with the query, you can only retrieve the association eagerly when it makes sense for your app